# Maven/JUnit - Get older static suite junit technique to work in Maven

Tags: unit-testing, junit, maven, test-suite

I am switching a project from Ant to Maven. I have my unit tests in the correct location, but for whatever reason the maven surefire plugin only sees about 136 (out of 1136 total) of the tests.

When using Ant, we used the older test suite technique of:

```
public class GatherTests{
  public static Test suite(){
    ... add tests ...
    return testSuite;
  }
}
```

as our runner. I haven't been able to determine how to get this to work using Surefire. I am using junit 3.8.1 with Maven 2.0. Does anyone know if this is possible? One thing I tried is:

```
-Dtest=GatherTests
```

with no luck. Many of our tests exist in classes that do not immediately inherit from junit.framework.TestCase, so that may be why surefire is having trouble gathering them. I will go through the logs now to see what it is missing.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: I looked into it more, and it is skipping tests that extend TestCase directly. It always skips the same ones, but they seem no different than others that are being included. I did notice that if a package includes multiple unit test classes, surefire is only running one of them. However, other packages that only include one class are being skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figured it out shortly after posting this.

[Maven Surefire Plugin Page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

On there it says:

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "Test".
> - "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "Test".
> - "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "TestCase".

The tests that were not being run matched the pattern **/*Tests.java. I added an inclusion rule, and they are all running now.